# Context menu copy/paste in VS code errors - RMC

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to have context menu copy/paste in VS code output errors - in Right Mouse Click.
Is it possible to get it in VS code ?
In cells I have it, but in output errors the only possibility is to use Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V.

Any ideas how to do it would be much appreciated.

Is there an extension maybe to install it ? I use Python on windows 10 x64.

Comment: what's RMC? "right mouse click"? And are you talking about Jupyter Notebook cell outputs?

Comment: I just asked about this here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/discussions/13904

Comment: Yes, Right Mouse Click - RMC. Yes, I am talking about Jupyter Notebook cell outputs. Is there any solution for this ?